# How to concatenate char?

Tags: c#, string, char, concatenation

My skills in C-sharp are basic but I stumbled on the "concatenation" part

When I concatenate the following code it works without a problem:

```
string a, b, c;
          a = "Bon";
          b = "jour";
          c = a + b;
          Console.WriteLine(c);
          Console.ReadLine();
```

Console result=      Bonjour

Now I try to do the same with char.

```
 char c1, c2, c3;
          c1 = 'B';
          c2 = 'j';
          c3 = c1 + c2;
          Console.WriteLine(c3);
          Console.ReadLine();
```

Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So that's what I try, since I learned how to cast.

```
 char c1, c2, c3;
          c1 = 'B';
          c2 = 'j';
          c3 = (char) c1 + c2;
          Console.WriteLine(c3);
          Console.ReadLine();
```

Same error.

It's not that I have the need to concatenate 2 characters, I'm just learning.
I just don't understand why this cast isn't possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off topic, but it is not correct to concatenate 2 characters and store it in a `char` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A char is an integral type and your performing math with those operations just as in c.

You need to create a string if you want a string  and then you can concatenate a char or a string.

Furthermore you should be using StringBuilder for this.

See also https://github.com/juliusfriedman/net7mma_core/blob/master/Common/Extensions/StringExtensions.cs#L315

Comment: I see, first it's now obvious to me that I can't store 2 chars in 1 char.
Secondly now I see that when I concatenate in the ConsoleWrite it gives me numbers. Thanks, makes perfectly sense now.

Comment: No problemo, one is glad to be of service.